# get song name while running in the background?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Is there a way for my android app to run in the background and perform an action when the current media being played matches some variable? for example:

```
String songThatIWant = "Killer Queen";

if (songThatIsCurrentlyPlaying = songThatIWant)
{
     //do stuff
}
```

but in the background? I'm planning to have my app send a notification asking if i want the lyrics to the song if it knows it when the song starts playing. Would I put the code in MainActivity.java, or would I create a separate activity specifically for running in the background? Thanks :)

Comment: You have to use a service and bind it to your activity, there is a lot to digest https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services so maybe this repo https://github.com/cutiko/Soliloquio

Comment: You know, that strings have to be compare with String1.equals("String2")?